# Why does ESX require so many restarts?

Tags: vmware-esxi

So more curiosity than anything while I wait for my upgrades but:

I can upgrade all the packages in my Linux desktop, without one single restart. ESX is Linux based (or BSD?) why is it that when applying updates it almost always requires a restart?

Comment: Do you pay for Ksplice? Every kernel update means a reboot for my Linux boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESXi is most defintely not Linux or BSD based. The console that you can SSH into looks like a Unix shell, but the kernel that is running is custom.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX#Technical_description

> As of version 4.1, VMWare has dropped development of ESX and now focuses exclusively on ESXi which does not include a Linux kernel.

The code that the kernel runs is the bare-minimum needed to be a hypervisor. Any given patch will likely be for kernel or device-driver-related code, so the reboot is necessary for the changed code to be loaded.

ESXi is intended to be run in a cluster, so the planned downtime of a single host should not cause any outages for your guests.

Comment: I stand corrected. I wasn't worried so much about downtime, it is in a cluster as you say. The hosts themselves take quite a while to restart, install ESXi 5.5, Restart, Stage updates, remediate, restart again.

Comment: For one, you only install ESXi once, right? So the restart related to installation is a one time event. Secondly, in all of my time using various flavors of ESXi, remediating the hosts has required but a single reboot. I'd hardly call that excessive.

Comment: It was excessive in this instance as it required a) ESX upgrade b) ESX updates c) Dell updates (openmanage etc) obviously not all directly to ESXi. Spread that over 6 hosts and it added up to hours of just sitting around waiting.  Like I said, it wasn't a big deal just curious as to why it was required, I was under the incorrect impression that it was a Linux kernel.